# AngularJS call HtppGet method from view gives infinite loop

Tags: php, angularjs

So I have a controller that contains two **http** get methods, seeing I don't want to create a second controller that does exactly the same but with a parameter.

**View:**

```
<div ng-init="getContacts(<?php echo $user->id ?>)';">
                <div class="cblock">

                        contact
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div ng-controller="ContactListCtrl"> 

                    <div>
                        <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index>
                            {{contact.firstname}} 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
angularControllers.controller('ContactListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.company_id;    
$scope.contacts;
$scope.allcontacts;    
$scope.getContacts = function ($id) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/contact.php?user_id='+$id
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.contacts = response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        alert(response.data, response.status);
    });
};
$scope.getAllContacts = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/contact.php'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.allcontacts = response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        alert(response.data, response.status);
    });
};
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php 

require_once('api_init.php');


if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $company = Company::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($company);
}
if(isset($_GET['company_id']))
{
    $contact = Contact::find_all_withcompanyID($_GET['company_id']);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($contact);   
}
else 
{
     $contact = Contact::find_all();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($contact);   
}
```

How can I one of the two functions and retrieve the data to be used in the div? Right now the getContacts() in the ng-init results in an infinite error, I guess due to dirty tracking?

Comment: show contact.php code.

Comment: Now shown in mainpost. The json result is working though, just not when I call the method from outside that angular file (so in the view).